# Use JavaFX 8 controls with 2.2 controls in JRubyFX

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, jrubyfx

Is there a way to use JavaFX 8 with JRubyFx (which uses JavaFX 2.2 by default). Would it be possible to use JavaFX 8 controls within a 2.2 framework? For example could I use an 8 Tab with a 2.2 TabPane?